# How to add Security Constraint in web.xml file?

Tags: web.xml

I am having numerous jsp files..depends on login(user/admin) i want that files to be viewed to specific user or admin..how can i get done it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I better suggest to a tutorial I have my self been through and I implemented my self this tutorial and now I am also integrating security to my existing WEB application. [Follow the link](http://heraclitusonsoftware.wordpress.com/software-development/spring/simple-web-application-with-spring-security-part-1/). I hope it help.

**Edit:** This is what exactly you need [Web Configuration for security](http://www.springbyexample.org/examples/simple-spring-security-webapp.html#simple-spring-security-webapp-web-config)