# How to redirect to login page after a inactive time?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have project (Java, JSF) and I need a way to redirect to login.xhtml page after idle time (inactive)

what should I add to my code ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Redirecting user to home page when idle for a given period of time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23454113/redirecting-user-to-home-page-when-idle-for-a-given-period-of-time)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Solve my problem by adding  JavaScript on each page except login page, I set it the timeout 15 minutes then redirect to login page and call logout function automatically.

```
<script>
            var time = new Date().getTime();

            document.onmousemove = function(event) {
                time = new Date().getTime();
            }

            document.onkeypress = function() {
                time = new Date().getTime();
            }

            function refresh() {
                if (new Date().getTime() - time >= 900000) {
                    document.getElementById("hiddenForm:gotoRegButton").click();
                    alert("Session expired please login again");
                    location.href = '../../../login/';
                } else {
                    setTimeout(refresh, 900000);
                }
            }

            setTimeout(refresh, 1000);
        </script>

        <h:form id="hiddenForm" style="display: none;">
            <h:commandButton id="gotoRegButton"
                action="#{mbLogin.logout()}" >
                <f:ajax execute="@form" render="statsData" />
                </h:commandButton>
        </h:form>
```

And for prevent accessing any another page when login flag is false, I added a below function on each page which checks the login flag before go to requested URL.

```
 @PostConstruct
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    public void checkLoginFlag() {
        boolean loginFlag = LoginController.loginFlag;
        if (!loginFlag) {
            redirect("../../login");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why not simply use `p:idleMonitor`? That will also prevent issues with multiple tabs.

Answer (score 2):

Two concepts that already exist and work together:

1. redirect to the login page for unauthenticated connections

Tomcat recognizes an authenticated connection by a session cookie. If that cookie is missing or contains an invalid value, and the web application declares security constraints in web.xml the container (Tomcat?) will automatically force the user to login. This may happen via an application-provided login page.
[How to add Security Constraint in web.xml file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9224386/how-to-add-security-constraint-in-web-xml-file)

2. timeout the sessions after inactivity

If the application declares that a session should expire after some time the container will simply invalidate the session when there was no activity. Furthe requests come in as unauthenticated and will be redirected to the login page.
[Default session timeout for Apache Tomcat applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14433070/default-session-timeout-for-apache-tomcat-applications)

Even though I sent references to Tomcat, the definitions need to be done in web.xml and will get effective on any compliant servlet container.

So ensure your web.xml file contains these snippets:

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>restricted methods</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint/>
</security-constraint>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>30</session-timeout><!-- 30 minutes -->
</session-config>
```

Comment: Answer is Spring related. It is possible to do without Spring as well.

Comment: Answer focuses on backend while I feel a frontend solution is wanted

Comment: @VasilLukach Where is the relation to Sprint?

Comment: @ Hiran Chaudhuri, Thanks, thats works with me , but i need to redirect automatically to login.xhtml page after session time out value , is any possible way to do that ?

Comment: Upon the next request the container will automatically redirect. If you need that done without the user clicking in the browser you need to add some javascript. I do not have that at hand.